Replace double quotes with blank space in Tibco Spotfire
I am trying to remove the double quote in a column and replace with blank space in spotfire calculated column using below formula
``
RXReplace([mycolumn], "\"", "")
``
I am getting the error for this.
If someone knows the solution please help me

try \ instead of \

Tried adding \ already. It is not working

Try this: it worked for me
RXReplace([mycolumn],'\\"','','g')


Yes. It is working for me. Please explain me what 'g' stands here

global substitution. It is in the parameter description.
Arg4 specifies the options for the replacement:
"g" specifies that if Arg2 matches more than once then all matches should be substituted.
